# how to checkbox checked base on condition in datatable

Tags: jquery, datatables

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
        function tax_type(x) {
            return (x == 1) ? "<?=lang('percentage')?>" : "<?=lang('fixed')?>";
        }

        oTable = $('#CURData').dataTable({
            "aaSorting": [[2, "asc"], [3, "asc"]],
            "aLengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, 100, -1], [10, 25, 50, 100, "<?= lang('all') ?>"]],
            "iDisplayLength": <?= $Settings->rows_per_page ?>,
            'bProcessing': true, 'bServerSide': true,
            'sAjaxSource': '<?= admin_url('system_settings/mapLocations') ?>',
            'fnServerData': function (sSource, aoData, fnCallback) {
                aoData.push({
                    "name": "<?= $this->security->get_csrf_token_name() ?>",
                    "value": "<?= $this->security->get_csrf_hash() ?>"
                });
                $.ajax({'dataType': 'json', 'type': 'POST', 'url': sSource, 'data': aoData, 'success': fnCallback});
            },
            "aoColumns": [{"bSortable": false, "mRender": checkbox}, { "bSortable": false, "mRender": img_hl }, null, null, null, null, null, null]
        }).fnSetFilteringDelay().dtFilter([
            
            {column_number: 2, filter_default_label: "[<?=lang('code');?>]", filter_type: "text", data: []},
            {
                column_number: 3,
                filter_default_label: "[<?=lang("name");?>]",
                filter_type: "text", data: []
            },
            {
                column_number: 4,
                filter_default_label: "[<?=lang("phone");?>]",
                filter_type: "text", data: []
            },
            {
                column_number: 5,
                filter_default_label: "[<?=lang("email");?>]",
                filter_type: "text", data: []
            },
            {
                column_number: 6,
                filter_default_label: "[<?=lang("address");?>]",
                filter_type: "text", data: []
            },
        ], "footer");
    });
```

[image]

as per above image. I need checkbox checked if status is 1.
How it's possible using datatable

datatable data is retrieved from database on load.

I upload both HTML and Javascript code for these.

Answer (score 0):

Issue is resolve now. Thanks for Viewer.

Solutions is as below. I update "mRender" and create function for my custom checkbox

```js
"aoColumns": [{"bSortable": false, "mRender": function ( data, type, row ) {
                    
                    var location= [<?php echo '"'.implode('","', $map_location).'"' ?>];
                    if(jQuery.inArray( data, location )==-1){
                        return '<div class="text-center"><input class="checkbox multi-select" type="checkbox" name="val[]" value="' + data + '" /></div>';
                    }
                    else{
                        return '<div class="text-center"><input checked class="checkbox multi-select" type="checkbox" name="val[]" value="' + data + '" /></div>';
                    }
                    //return '<div class="text-center"><input class="checkbox multi-select" type="checkbox" name="val[]" value="' + data + '" /></div>';
                    
                }
            }, { "bSortable": false, "mRender": img_hl }, null, null, null, null, null]
```